# Replace and Reverse - Array Methods math problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

This is a math problem that I have been struggling with!

*Replace and Reverse*

Write a JS function that receives an array of strings, reverses the string and make the first letter
of each element upper-case.
The input comes as an array of strings.
The output must be the resulting array elements, separated by a space into element with id
“result” like text/string.

Input: `['inutfos',tneduts, 'tpircsavaj']`
Expected output: `Softuni Student Javascript`.

I will appreciate it if you help me solve it with array methods!

This is the code I was trying:

```js
    function replaceAndReverse(arr) {
    
        let newArray = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
            let currentElement = arr[i]
            currentElement.toString()
            newArray.push(currentElement)
            currentElement.reverse()
        }
    
        console.log(newArray)
    }
    replaceAndReverse(['abc','cde']);
```

Comment: Try something and post your code here this isn't a code providing site

Comment: Yeah please post it here, that's how it goes here this question of your's won't help anyone on earth as you haven't followed the right path to question please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Now your question looks a little better although I've already answered it.

Comment: what is the specific math problem here? does your teacher mentioned some?

Comment: Hi, @NinaScholz. We are supposed to be using Array methods in order to reverse the characters in the strings as well as the elements in the array. You can see the input and the expected output in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the array,

- map the result of

  - splitting into characters
  - make the first element of the array to upper case
  - join this array to a single string
  - return this string as element of a new array
- join this array
- and assign this sting to the wanted element.

```js
var array = ['inutfos', 'tneduts', 'tpircsavaj'];


document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = array
    .map(s => {
        var characters = Array.from(s).reverse();
        characters[0] = characters[0].toUpperCase();
        return characters.join('');
    })
    .join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const strArray = ['inutfos', 'tneduts', 'tpircsavaj']
strArray.map(s=>s.split('').reverse().map((i,index)=>index===0?i.toUpperCase():i).join(''))
```

Basically somebody wants to test your JavaScript knowledge of Array and Strings.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```js
//Write a JS function that receives an array of strings
const formatStrings = function(strings) {
  //reverses the string 
  strings = strings.map(string => string.split('').reverse().join(''));
  //and make the first letter of each element upper-case. 
  strings = strings.map(string => string[0].toUpperCase() + string.substr(1));
  //The input comes as an array of strings. The output must be the resulting array elements, separated by a space into element with id “result” like text/string.
  return strings.join(' ');
}


console.log(formatStrings(['inutfos', 'tneduts', 'tpircsavaj']));
```